# Is it possible to retrieve a web template (not a site template) in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, template, web-template

You can get a site template in SharePoint Online by going to site settings and clicking save as template (it will be stored in the solution gallery).

I have seen articles on how to create custom web templates, but is there a way to generate them for a web that already exists?

Forgive me if this is a silly question. I am still reading up on web templates.

Comment: Users create web templates on the Save as Template page (or through code that uses the SaveAsTemplate method of the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb class). [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/aa979709(v%3doffice.14)). Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SaveAsTemplate method is not available in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Yes. In SharePoint Online, you can use `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` using PnP PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web template is persisted in the SharePoint database as a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Solution, which is a file that has a `.wsp` extension. The `.wsp` file is stored in the Solutions Gallery of the site collection. The solution can also be deployed as a sandboxed solution.

Users create web templates on the **Save as Template** page (or through code that uses the [SaveAsTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms415826(v%3doffice.14)) method of the [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms473942(v%3doffice.14)) class).

**Source**: [Web Templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/aa979709(v%3doffice.14))

**Issue**: Unfortunately, the `SaveAsTemplate` method is not available in SharePoint Online.

**Solution**:

In SharePoint Online, you can use `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` using PnP PowerShell to generate a provisioning site template from a web.

**References**:

1. [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate)
2. [Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)

Comment: I think that's a site template, but I'm not sure because I'm slightly confused by the difference. I found this answer that explains the difference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/94234/90631